# k8s multiple taints ans labels - relationship

Tags: kubernetes

I created a node group with two labels and two taints.

```
spec:
  labels:
    key1: "val1"
    key2: "val2"
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: key1
    value: val2
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: key2
    value: val2
```

I have 2 kinds of pods:

either

```
 nodeSelector:
   key1: "val1"
 
 tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: key1
    value: val1
```

or

```
 nodeSelector:
   key2: "val2"
 
 tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: key2
    value: val2
```

None of the pods arrives with both `key1` `val1` and `key2` `val2`.

Apparently no pod is being scheduled on my new node group.

Is it because the logic between `label` and `taints` keyss is `and`?

Is it possible to define `or` between labels and between taints? so that my pods will be scheduled?

Answer (score 0):

Because of taints, your pod is not able to deploy on the node.
You need to tolerate both taint key1 and key2.

Here is my understanding, Node Selector is a feature to put a pod on a node which has a label you specified with nodeSelector. Whereas, Taint is a feature not to schedule a pod without toleration.
For example, if you modify a kernel parameter on a node and don't want to schedule pods. You may not set toleration to the pods, then the pod will not be scheduled on the node. However, if you want, you need to specify nodeselector to schedule a pod on the node and tolerate the taint, then the pod will be scheduled on the node.

According to the document of kubernetes, Use case of taints is as follows. I think there is no use case what you tried.

> Dedicated Nodes: If you want to dedicate a set of nodes for exclusive
> use by a particular set of users, you can add a taint to those nodes
> (say, kubectl taint nodes nodename dedicated=groupName:NoSchedule) and
> then add a corresponding toleration to their pods (this would be done
> most easily by writing a custom admission controller). The pods with
> the tolerations will then be allowed to use the tainted (dedicated)
> nodes as well as any other nodes in the cluster. If you want to
> dedicate the nodes to them and ensure they only use the dedicated
> nodes, then you should additionally add a label similar to the taint
> to the same set of nodes (e.g. dedicated=groupName), and the admission
> controller should additionally add a node affinity to require that the
> pods can only schedule onto nodes labeled with dedicated=groupName.
>
> Nodes with Special Hardware: In a cluster where a small subset of
> nodes have specialized hardware (for example GPUs), it is desirable to
> keep pods that don't need the specialized hardware off of those nodes,
> thus leaving room for later-arriving pods that do need the specialized
> hardware. This can be done by tainting the nodes that have the
> specialized hardware (e.g. kubectl taint nodes nodename
> special=true:NoSchedule or kubectl taint nodes nodename
> special=true:PreferNoSchedule) and adding a corresponding toleration
> to pods that use the special hardware. As in the dedicated nodes use
> case, it is probably easiest to apply the tolerations using a custom
> admission controller. For example, it is recommended to use Extended
> Resources to represent the special hardware, taint your special
> hardware nodes with the extended resource name and run the
> ExtendedResourceToleration admission controller. Now, because the
> nodes are tainted, no pods without the toleration will schedule on
> them. But when you submit a pod that requests the extended resource,
> the ExtendedResourceToleration admission controller will automatically
> add the correct toleration to the pod and that pod will schedule on
> the special hardware nodes. This will make sure that these special
> hardware nodes are dedicated for pods requesting such hardware and you
> don't have to manually add tolerations to your pods.
>
> Taint based Evictions: A per-pod-configurable eviction behavior when
> there are node problems, which is described in the next section.

*1: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#example-use-cases